# How would I go about finding the sum of a non-infinite summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, geometric-series

I am given:
$\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{n(1+k)}$
and I am honestly at a loss on how to proceed. I'm thinking to use a geometric series formula, but the index starts at k=1, and there is a "n" in my summation. How would I shift and proceed?

Thank you

Comment: Trick $1$: $2^{n(1+k)}=(2^n)^{1+k}=b^{1+k}$ is a geometric series with base $b=2^n$. 

Trick $2$: $$\sum_{k=l}^m b^k = b^l+b^{l+1}+\ldots+b^m = b^l(1+b+\ldots + b^{m-l})=b^l\sum_{k=0}^{m-l}b^k.$$ 

Trick $3$: $$\sum_{k=0}^m b^{k+l}=\sum_{k=0}^m b^kb^l=b^l\sum_{k=0}^m b^k.$$ 

Using all of these, you can get it down to a geometric series times some factors.

Comment: @jwhite: you should post your comment as an answer (perhaps prefixed by "Hint:").

Answer (score 0):

Since $2^{n(1+k)}=2^n2^{nk}$ and $n$ is not the indexing variable, we may rewrite the series as $2^n\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{nk}$. Next, let $2^n=t$; then the series becomes $2^n\sum_{k=1}^nt^k=t+t^2+t^3+...+t^n$.

From here it is rather straightfoward. Factor out a $t$ from the series, so that you have $t(1+t+t^2+...+t^{n-1})$. By the sum of a geometric series formula, the larger factor is equal to $\frac{1-t^n}{1-t}$. Re-multiply this with the factor of $t$ to get $\frac{t-t^{n+1}}{1-t}$, and then substitute $t$ with $2^n$ to get $\frac{2^n-(2^n)^{n+1}}{1-2^n}=\frac{2^n-2^{n^2+n}}{1-2^n}$.

Finally, re-introduce the $2^n$ that we factored out at the beginning. This leaves you with $\frac{2^{2n}-2^{n^2+2n}}{1-2^n}$.

And that's it!